# What happens if I use update-alternatives to manage python versions instead of virtualenv or pyenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

I know that there are somethings like **virtualenv** and **pyenv** to manage python versions in a single machine. But what happens if I change the default python version using **update-alternatives**? AFAIK, it will make system-wise change while **virtualenv** or **pyenv** can manage version for each project (or directory). Then when I only works for a single project at once, is it OK to simply use **update-alternatives** instead? Since somethings like **pip** are run as `python -m pip ...` so it seems safe for me to manage pip packages in this way also. What should I consider further when I only works for one project at once?

Comment: Why _would_ you want to use update-alternatives? I don't think it will properly handle different sets of libraries, like virtualenv can.

Comment: @AKX For example, I want to use python 3.7 instead of 3.8 regarding to supported libraries.

Comment: I think you'll have a better time with pyenv + virtualenv.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your comment but it is a little bit inconvenient for me because I sometimes just do turn on VS Code, fix several lines and run...  To do that I have to care about python interpreter versions.

Comment: VS Code has excellent support for virtualenvs. To test your code on multiple interpreter versions, also look at tox + pyenv + tox-pyenv.

Comment: @AKX Oh, I got the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK. Now I understand what I misunderstood.

By using

- **update-alternatives**, I can change the default python version.
- **pyenv** or **virtualenv**, I can isolate environments of projects.

Let's assume that I have project *A*, *B* for python**3.7** and C for python**3.8**. 
And Project *A* and *B* require pip package X-**1.0** and X-**1.3**, respectively. 
In that case I can use **pyenv** or **virtualenv**, but **update-alternatives** cannot handle the situation though it can change python version to 3.7 (and load corresponding packages for it) for project *A* and *B*.